# Performance of asynchronous programming and parallel programming locked to single thread

Tags: c#, regex, multithreading

I was writing some code for a list that parses a dictionary via regex and whatnot for DateTime elements. The following code DOES work, and works rather well. However, when going back I am noticing this Parallel.ForEach I had written. My question is simple; is there a performance gain in using a Parallel.ForEach if I am locking the thread? I feel as if this defeats the entire purpose.

Also, I feel as if the same idea/question applies to the async situation, since I am locking the thread.

```
namespace StackOverflowExample
{
    public class ScheduledTimeList : List<ScheduledTime>
    {
        public static ScheduledTimeList Parse(
            Dictionary<string, string> dateTimeStrings, string startRegex,
            string endRegex, object sync)
        {
            var scheduledTimes = new ScheduledTimeList();

            Parallel.ForEach(from dt in dateTimeStrings.AsParallel()
                             select ParseScheduledTime(dt, startRegex, endRegex), dt =>
            {
                lock (sync) { scheduledTimes.Add(dt); }
            });

            return scheduledTimes;
        }

        private static ScheduledTime ParseScheduledTime(
            KeyValuePair<string, string> dateTime, string startRegex,
            string endRegex)
        {
            var startString =
                dateTime.Key + " " + new Regex(startRegex).Match(dateTime.Value);
            var endString =
                dateTime.Key + " " + new Regex(endRegex).Match(dateTime.Value);

            var startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startString);
            var endDateTime = DateTime.Parse(endString);

            return new ScheduledTime(startDateTime,
                endDateTime);
        }

        private static async Task<ScheduledTime> ParseScheduledTimeAsync(
            KeyValuePair<string, string> dateTime, string startRegex,
            string endRegex)
        {
            var startString = Task.Run(() =>
                dateTime.Key + " " + new Regex(startRegex).Match(dateTime.Value).Value);
            var endString = Task.Run(() =>
                dateTime.Key + " " + new Regex(endRegex).Match(dateTime.Value).Value);
            await Task.WhenAll(startString, endString);

            var startDateTime = await Task.Run(() =>
                DateTime.Parse(startString.Result));
            var endDateTime = await Task.Run(() =>
                DateTime.Parse(endString.Result));

            return new ScheduledTime(startDateTime,
                endDateTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that appears to be CPU intensive. I would think that the performance of this code would be worse trying to do it in parallel. Have you tried the code using a single thread?

Comment: `is there a performance gain` - What do your performance measurements tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some misunderstandings, issues with analysis and wrong decisions.

First, if you start something like Parallel.ForEach or AsParallel or Tasks,
that is pretty much same, all running on top of TPL, then there is not one thread, but many or one, it all depends on load balancing, but **my point is, that locking does not ensure that all parts will be running on the same thread. Instead lock is ensuring that in any given time, only one thread will be running inside a locked area. Certainly not same thing**.

Now the second issue here is, that you made usual beginners mistake. Introducing too much concurrency does not help. Certainly I see a issue in Parse method, where you first spark inner parallel block to get results out if AsParallel(), PLINQ, approach, there it works fully concurrently, but then you return back IEnumerable to Parallel.ForEach, forcing PLINQ to synchronize results back into IEnumerable. That is bad decision for performance.

And the third mistake is to use old collections like List etc in concurrent code. Concurrent code is playing best on top of concurrent collections.
Here it would mean using ConcurrentBag instead List.

```
 public class ScheduledTimeList : ConcurrentBag<ScheduledTime>
```

So in the end it could look like this in Parse method:

```
var scheduledTimes = new ScheduledTimeList();

dateTimeStrings
.AsParallel()
.ForAll(dts =>
{
  var dt = ParseScheduledTime(dts, startRegex, endRegex);
  scheduledTimes.Add(dt);//add's items concurently into bag,
});
```

Parallel/asynchronous/concurrent programming is hard stuff, and it really needs lots of study even beyond tasks, class Parallel, PLINQ and async/await.

Please take my advice as pointers for further study, take it easy and step by step, I do not want to discourage from it or sound as if it is impossible to understand this, it is just broader issue topic...

Answer (score 1):

> is there a performance gain in using a Parallel.ForEach if I am locking the thread?

Quite the opposite.  You are incurring overhead to run in parallel then immediately causing all of your threads to run in a serialized manner because the entire code block is controlled by a lock statement.